# Get nested dictionary from ImmutableMultiDict without iteration

Tags: javascript, python, flask

**title seems like a common problem but before marking as duplicate post please read at first**

I am passing a `javaScript object` via `POST` method to `Flask`. But I think it converts to `JSON` format(due to insufficient knowledge I am not confident about this statement). On the client-side, I have printed the value of the JavaScript object and got

```
{
  "0001_Summer": {
    "value": [
      "value_05",
      "value_02",
      "value_03"
    ]
  },
  "0003_Spring": {
    "value": [
      "All",
      "value_04",
      "value_03"
    ]
  },
  "0002_Winter": {
    "value": [
      "value_04",
      "value_07",
      "value_02"
    ]
  },
  "Query": "56"
}
```

The way of submission from JavaScript is as like as follows in my case

```
function POST_Query_data() {
    hiddenform = document.createElement("form")
    hiddenform.style.visibility = "hidden";
    hiddenform.method = "POST";
    // json_for_backend this is the final json in my case

    for ([key, value] of Object.entries(json_for_backend)) {
        i_1 = document.createElement("input");
        i_1.name = key;
        i_1.value = JSON.stringify(value);
        hiddenform.appendChild(i_1);
    }
    document.getElementById("body").appendChild(hiddenform);
    hiddenform.submit();
}
```

While I click on `submit` then `POST_Query_data` is triggered.

After passing this object via `POST` method in Flask I have printed `request.form` and got

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('0001_Summer', '{"value":["value_05","value_02","value_03"]}'), ('0003_Spring', '{"value":["All","value_04","value_03"]}'), ('0002_Winter', '{"value":["value_04","value_07","value_02"]}'), ('Query', '"56"')])
```

By following the [documentation](https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.to_dict.html) I have converted this `ImmutableMultiDict` to a regular `dict` type

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def foo(name=None):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        converted_dict = {}
        converted_dict = request.form.to_dict()

    return render_template('index.html',name=name)
```

After printing `converted_dict` I have found

```
{'0001_Summer': '{"value":["value_05","value_02","value_03"]}', '0003_Spring': '{"value":["All","value_04","value_03"]}', '0002_Winter': '{"value":["value_04","value_07","value_02"]}', 'Query': '"56"'}
```

where it is seen that the value of each key(`eg: 0001_Summer`) is a string while I need them also in a `dict` type. I have found tons of post regarding conversion of `string to dict` and followed [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary).

```
import ast
for a in converted_dict:
    for key, val in ast.literal_eval(converted_dict[a]).items():
        # done processing with "val"(dict type from string)
```

But I am looking for any faster way to convert from `ImmutableMultiDict` to a `nested dict` form as in the above process I have to iterate using a `for loop` which I believe for a large data will cause a overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try property `Request.json`. In your case, it's `request.json`.

Learn to use the API doc: [`flask.Request`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request).

Comment: I have added the method of POST which I have followed from JavaScript to Flask in the ques. Do I need to change anything in that function(`POST_Query_data`)? After checking `if request.method == 'POST'` I have tried `print(request.json)` but it has given me `None`.